# Stock Historical Data Retrieval Slow in Excel for Large Amounts of Data

Tags: excel, performance, stock

Using the Excel stock data type, and the stockhistory() function, I download large amounts of historical OHLCV data for 1,000+ stocks over hundreds of days. These large amounts of data seem to be 'throttled' by the data provider, forcing me to wait a long time for the data retrieval to complete. I've tried Google searches on this issue, but I'm not finding any useful results. I am willing to pay a reasonable price for faster data retrieval. I have two questions:

1. Can anyone provide more detailed information on why the data retrieval is so slow (throttled ?) for larger requests?
2. What provider offers historical stock data for rapid retrieval at a good price?

I have found some improvement by retrieving smaller chunks of data, but this takes too much manual work. I have tried data retrieval in R, but it seems the same throttling of data is taking place. I've tried Google Sheets, but it is excruciatingly slow for the amounts of data I need.

Comment: It is not uncommon for data providers to throttle API performance, because it's how they make money.  "Oh, you want to go from a 'bronze account' to a 'silver account', that's $X per month."

Comment: Thank you, Max. Can you recommend any providers?